# Inserir tag no build do Docker não está funcionando

Tags: docker

Eu tenho um dockerfile no meu projeto que usa a imagem abaixo:
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8 as builder

Quando eu executo o build é executado tudo perfeitamente:
docker build -t trocadilho/server:1.0 .

Mas o problema é que a nomeação da tag não funciona, quando executo o comando "sudo docker images" minhas imagens são criadas como

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VrdD.png

Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente isso acontece quando o build da imagem é realizado e terminado com algum erro.

Utilize o comando para gerar uma tag para sua imagem:

```
docker tag image-id trocadilho/server:1.0
```